# Weird color problem after install Ubuntu MATE

Tags: 16.04, mate, colors

I don't know what exactly this problem called. Somehow, the 'R' in RGB turned into Blue.

Please check below screenshots:

**Weird color**
[image: Ubuntu Mate]

**Normal**
[image: Mac OSX]

What was happened? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

just a guess, try to change color depth of your remote desktop client. From your screenshots, you seems to use a Mac machine. I do not know exactly where it would be located but you should have an option that allows you to decrease color depth and you could see if this fix your issue

Till next time 
See ya

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm using Microsoft Remote Desktop on Mac, I also tried to change color depth from 24bit to 32bit but no changes at all. I also tried Windows's `mstsc` too, but same weird color...